# clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This most likely just a frustration syntax error on my part. But resizeTime just won't clear. The timer just keeps going regardless of using clearInterval on it more than once. Any ideas folks? I have posted my real code:

```
  var resizeTime; // declared outside of wrapper function to INSURE no second declaration will occur
  var myTransitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();

  $(window).bind('adapt', function(){
        console.log('start', resizeTime);
        resizeTime = setInterval(function(){
              console.log('go', resizeTime);
              methods.relayoutChildren.apply(self);
        }, 5);
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('sNend', resizeTime);
              clearInterval(resizeTime);
        },1000);

  });

  $('#allies-wrap').bind(myTransitionEvent, function(){
        console.log('end', resizeTime);
        clearInterval(resizeTime);
        methods.relayoutChildren.apply(self);
  });
```

Here is a sample log from chrome:

```
  start undefined
  start 8215
  (10) go 8218
  start 8218
  start 8221
  (256) go 8224
  (2) sNend 8224
  (9) go 8224
  sNend 8224
  (3) go 8224
  sNend 8224
  (2596) go 8224
```

for those who don't know chrome's log, (2596) means 2596 occurrences of an identical log.

Comment: have you got any error ?

Comment: no error, from my IDE or the browser; except 'go' thousands of times in the log.

Comment: Can we have more detailed example of code that running the timer (the code in `adapt` binding is working perfectly starting and clearing the interval http://jsfiddle.net/vHn9r/)

Comment: are you sure you haven't got a loop that call this piece of code (causing the interval to be reconfigured). What I want to say is that are you sure the bind is called only one time ?

Comment: @JuicyScripter 'adapt' is fireing, I can see it in the log. This is a mod of jQuery RoundAbout to allow for a responsive roundabout that responds to its parent's size changing with a css3 transition.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, any chances it runs multiple times? Try to clear interval right before you running it: `clearInterval(resizeTime); resizeTime = setInterval(...)`

Comment: @JuicyScripter not that is just the thing. I have everything logging to the console, and the event that starts the timer runs only once! And I can see the events that end the timer run as well, but the timer just keeps on going.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, try to print the interval id `console.log('go', resizeTime)` to figure out if it's not the same interval for some reason...

Comment: @JuicyScripter I had no idea you could do that. I have since edited my code a little and posted the log messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Transition event is not getting triggered but `adapt` event gets triggered again and again. So `resizeTime` changes before the active one gets cleared.
You can fix it ( at least make it better ) by clearing the interval before setting new one.

```
clearInterval(resizeTime);
resizeTime = setInterval(function(){
                  console.log('go', resizeTime);
                  methods.relayoutChildren.apply(self);
            }, 5);

clearTimeout(sNendTime);
sNendTime = setTimeout(function(){
              console.log('sNend', resizeTime);
              clearInterval(resizeTime);
        },1000);
```

EDIT:

What happens is

1. `adapt` event triggers
2. A new interval is set and interval id assigned to `resizeTime`
3. A new timeout is set
4. So now 2 things are active - 1 interval, 1 timeout
5. Before the time out delay elapses, again `adapt` event triggers
6. A new interval is set and interval id assigned to `resizeTime`
7. As `resizeTime` gets overwritten the id to previous interval is lost, but that interval still active
8. A new timeout is set
9. So now 4 things active - 2 intervals, 2 timeouts
10. It goes on
11. After 1000s , say there are 20 intervals , 20 timeouts active
12. First time out invokes the function and it clears the interval pointed by 20th value of `resizeTime`
13. So still 19 intervals and 19 timeouts active
14. It goes on
15. Even if `transitionevent` triggers it will only clear the latest interval

For your code to work there should be a `transitionevent` after each `adapt` event, but there is not. So we have to clear the active interval and active timeout so that there will be only one of each active at a time, and when timeout ends the function clears interval also.

Comment: Sir you are a scholar and a saint. That worked perfect, but I still don't understand why. The variable is only being declared once, so how can the repetition of it being set to an interval cause this problem? Shouldn't it just reset itself? Can a variable be multiple intervals?

Comment: :) . No it doesn't reset itself and points to only one at a time. See the EDIT, I have explained it. Thanks.

Comment: now that is cool. Thanks for an excellent answer, I just learned something new about js!